# WHS and 2TB disks: The system disk can be a jumpered WD EARS drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-home-server

As we all know WHS does not like the new disks with 4K sectors.

It's possible to use a western digital EARS drive, jumpered to emulate 512b sectors with the data disk with no issue.

What will happen with the system disk? Windows XP can work, but WHS has that strange filesystem that does not play well with anything.

Can the system disk be a 2TB disk jumpered to have 512b sectors?

Answer (score 0):

Request for firmware that allows for the change (acknowleged by WD is all)

http://community.wdc.com/t5/ideas/v1/ideapage/blog-id/internal_ideas/article-id/5/page/5#comments

Download location for one of the ears drives, no indication of new firmware?

http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?wdc_lang=en&fid=wdsfCaviar_Green

I read this as, the community is saying **it is 512b to the system already?** If you have other information showing it different I am interested.

The drive can be jumpered to do a 1 sector shift , that can help with compatability issues with some OSes.  The tech who sold me mine installed the jumper told me to leave it in, and he was right. I have never had any problem and I have teams of them on 2 raid controllers (intel and Highpoint) and On intel as singles. In XP and in windows 7. . I think I am the only person who never had a problem, and never sees this slowdown :-) I use Large clusters in formatting.

The Advanced format data http://www.wdc.com/global/products/features/?id=7

More AF data http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5655/p/227%2C294/c/123

Comment: Maybe the first versions. Newer drives (EARX) will only report 4k, and need a special utility to emulate the 512b. EARS drives have a jumper, =1, 512b emulation, =0 report 4k sectors

Comment: that makes perfect sence. so will you edit the question to earX? i dont know them well enough to comment.